# how to drop columns by passing variable name with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df as follows:

```
a <- data_frame(keep=c("hello", "world"),drop = c("nice", "work"))
a
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
   keep  drop
  (chr) (chr)
1 hello  nice
2 world  work
```

I can use `a  %>% select(-drop)`  to drop the column without problem. however, if I want to pass a variable to present `drop` column, then it returns error.

```
name <- "drop"
a  %>% select(-(name))
```

> Error in -(name) : invalid argument to unary operator

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `one_of` to find the column positions and then use `-` to drop it, `select(-one_of(name))`, if you check `?select`, the usage is documented in the *Drop variable* section in the *Examples*:

```
name <- "drop"
a %>% select(-one_of(name))

# A tibble: 2 × 1
#   keep
#  <chr>
#1 hello
#2 world
```

---

Or with `select_`, you need to paste `-` with the column names to drop them and pass the pasted column names to the `.dots` parameter if there are more than one column to be dropped:

```
name <- "drop"
a %>% select_(.dots = paste("-", name))

# A tibble: 2 × 1
#   keep
#  <chr>
#1 hello
#2 world
```

Comment: a simple question - generally when column names are in strings then we use `select_()` version right? when i tried this, didn't work

Comment: select_ is no longer advice. Can you update the solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can simple use

```
a <- data_frame(keep=c("hello", "world"),drop = c("nice", "work"))
select(a, -starts_with('drop'))
#   Source: local data frame [2 x 1]
#
#   keep
#   (chr)
# 1 hello
# 2 world
```

you have to search for some previously written solutions too. Please read the document here [Select/rename variables by name.DPLYR](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/select.html%22Select/rename%20variables%20by%20name%22)

I hope that does the job for you :)
@Psidom thanx for updating your answer.. but I will request upvoters for vote for me too as I recently became an active user and still am to get basic privileges on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `select_` with `setdiff`

```
a %>%
    select_(setdiff(names(.), name))
# A tibble: 2 × 1
#   keep
#   <chr>
#1 hello
#2 world
```

Comment: Notice that `select_` is not available anymore with modern versions of dplyr (as of August 2023). See [James Hirschorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359311/1719931) for how to do it with modern versions of dplyr.

Answer (score 4):

A few more possibilities:

```
name <- "drop"
a %>% `[<-`(name, value=NULL)
a %>% magrittr::inset(name,value=NULL)
a %>% purrr::modify_at(name,~NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could only get these solutions to work by first ungrouping the data using `ungroup`:

```
df <- df  %>%  ungroup  %>%  select(-hello)
```

Notice no quotation marks on the column name you want to drop (hello). Also, to remove multiple columns, just place a `,` after hello and add the second column.

Answer (score 1):

From the `?select_` help:

> dplyr used to offer twin versions of each verb suffixed with an underscore [...] However, dplyr now uses tidy evaluation semantics.  [...] Thus, the underscored versions are now superfluous.

The example given in `vignette("programming")`, similar to @Psidom's answer, is:

```
name <- "drop"
a %>% select(!all_of(name))
```

Alternatively, this one could create a function to drop columns, so that `drop` does not need quoting:

```
drop_columns <- function(data, cols) {
  data %>% select(!{{cols}})
}

drop_columns(a, drop)
```