# Standard Evaluation Version of select_() within do_()

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a function, that computes reliability estimates groupy by a factor variable. Therefore I wrote this not working function:

```
 notworkingfunction <- function(dat, grvar){  

   reldat <- dat%>%
     group_by_(grvar)%>%
     do_(data.frame(alpha = MBESS::ci.reliability(data.frame(dplyr::select_(., quote(-grvar))))))

   return(reldat)

 }

notworkingfunction(iris, "Species")
```

It seems to me, that the NSE of select_() causes the problems.
Every hints are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you had already noticed, `select_` is a quirky function. To use `select_` for dropping columns, you need to use the form `paste("-", grvar)` (See [how to drop columns by passing variable name with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819422/how-to-drop-columns-by-passing-variable-name-with-dplyrhttp://))

Once this is done, you don't need to use `do_` anymore. You can use `do` as usual

```
newfunction  <- function(dat, grvar){  

  reldat <- dat%>%
    group_by_(grvar)%>%
    do(data.frame(alpha = MBESS::ci.reliability(data.frame(dplyr::select_(., paste("-", grvar))))))

  return(reldat)
  }
```