# Specifying which columns to drop with standard evaluation using the tidyr function gather_() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to drop columns from the columns to be gathered using the `gather()` function in the R package `tidyr`.

This works fine when I specify what columns I want to gather (here, I'm gathering the `mpg`, `cyl`, and `disp` columns into `variable` and `val` columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select_("mpg", "cyl", "disp") %>% 
  gather_("variable", "val", gather_cols = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"))
```

Let's say I had four variables, and instead of specifying which to gather, I wanted to specify which to drop (`hp` in this next case). This, probably obviously, doesn't work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select_("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp") %>% 
  gather_("var", "val", gather_cols = c(-"hp"))
```

The suggestion to use `one_of` - as in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819422/how-to-drop-columns-by-passing-variable-name-with-dplyr) - doesn't seem to work. In a now-closed [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/109) for `tidyr`, it is suggested to use `dplyr::select_vars()`, but this doesn't seem to work, either.

How could this - specifying which columns to drop with standard evaluation using `gather()`?

Comment: `mtcars %>% gather_("k", "v", colnames(.)[!colnames(.) %in% c("hp", "am")])`?

Comment: Thanks! This works; I changed to this to parallel the example above: `mtcars %>% 
  select_("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp") %>% 
  gather_("variable", "val", colnames(.)[!colnames(.) %in% c("hp")])` boy, this is verbose and not easy to understand, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unfamiliar with what `tidyverse` loads and how it manages environments -- I usually use regular `tidyr` -- but using `tidyr::gather` instead of `gather_`, would allow you to use this syntax:

```
# here, gather takes the "key" and "value" args as objects
# as does dplyr::select
# and allows for additional objects off the data.frame
# to be passed as additional args

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(mpg, cyl, disp, hp) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(var, val, -hp)
```

Comment: Thanks. library(tidyverse) loads dplyr and tidyr (and a few other packages). In this case at least, the code above should work the same were each of the packages loaded on their own. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear - but I need to use standard evaluation (variables names are quoted - unlike how select() and gather() usually work). It's because I'm using this in a function and have to pass the variables as character strings.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
mtcars %>% 
    select_("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp") %>% 
    gather_("var", "val", select_vars(include = c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')))
```

or if you want to specify the excluded column:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select_("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp") %>% 
  gather(var, val, select_vars(include = -matches('hp')))
```