# How to delete tibble columns names of which is contained in vector?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, tibble

This allows me to delete single column:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,NA,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
c <- c(1,2,3,4,NA)
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
z<-tibble(a, b, c, d)
z
z<-select(z, -starts_with('c'))
z
```

(More examples here: [how to drop columns by passing variable name with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819422/how-to-drop-columns-by-passing-variable-name-with-dplyr) )

Now instead of giving name of single column I want to give a vector with column names that should be deleted. How to do that?

Comment: What exactly is not working with `z %>%
 select(-one_of(cols))`?

Comment: Or any of the methods [from this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4605206/903061). (The second answer is `select(-one_of(cols))`

Comment: @Gregor It works. Thank you!